# Return two values with CASE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question: here is the problem, in my table I have some clients in this format:

```
id | year | Month | Amount 
---+------+-------+--------
1  | 2016 | 02    | 250.00
2  | 2013 | 08    | 350.00
3  | 2015 | 12    | 450.00
4  | 2016 | 02    | 750.00
```

In my other table, I have a column `ClientStartDate` in this format `2015-12-15 00:00:00.000`. So if the client start date is on 15th day of the month, than in table above I need to have two records , first record for the date Client started his work and second record for the same client but for the next month. It should look like this, let's say that client with id=3 started on 2015-12-15,table should look like this:

```
id | year | Month | Amount 
---+------+-------+--------
1  | 2016 | 02    | 250.00
2  | 2013 | 08    | 350.00
3  | 2015 | 12    | 450.00
3  | 2016 | 01    | 150.00
4  | 2016 | 02    | 750.00
```

This is table where `ClientStartDate` comes from:

```
 id | Name   | ClientStartDate
 ---+--------+-------------------------
 1  | John   | 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
 2  | Anna   | 2013-08-01 00:00:00.000
 3  | Mike   | 2015-12-15 00:00:00.000
 4  | Nicolas| 2016-02-04 00:00:00.000
 5  | Monika | 2013-11-15 00:00:00.000
```

This is `FactTrans` table where `DateKey` comes from:

```
  id  | amount | DateKey
  ----+--------+----------
   1  | 208.67 | 20160201
   1  | 19.12  | 20160205
   2  | 55.42  | 20130820
   2  | 5.42   | 20130811
   4  | 23.98  | 20151121
   5  | 17.99  | 20140820
```

Here is full code that I tried:

```
select 
    t1.ID, 
    left(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4) as Year,
    left(right(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4), 2) as Month, 
    sum(t1.amount) as SumAmount
from 
    .dbo.FactTrans t1
inner join 
    dbo.Client t2 on t2.clientid = t1.clientid 
where 
    (left(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4) = year(t2.clientstartdate) 
     and left(right(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4), 2) = month(t2.clientstartdate)) 
    or 
    (case
        when left(right(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4), 2)= 1 
           then 12
           else left(right(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4), 2) - 1 
     end = month(t2.ClientStartDate) 
    and 
               case
                  when
                     month(t2.ClientStartDate) = 12 
                  then
                    LEFT(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4) - 1 
                  else
                     LEFT(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4)
               end
                    = year(t2.ClientStartDate) 
               and 
               case
                when 
                day(t2.ClientStartDate) = 15 
                then
                month(t2.ClientStartDate)  + 1
                else
                month(t2.ClientStartDate) 
                end
                = left(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4)
        )
group by t1.clientid, LEFT(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4)  ,left(right(cast(t1.datekey as varchar), 4), 2) 
order by t1.clientID
```

This case cover part where day = 15 but month =! 12, so here I only need to return next month and not next year. So my question is, can someone help me to write case where day=15 but month=12, and I need to return both next onth and next year for that client.

This case is WHERE statement.

Comment: Please provide your tables and the query.

Comment: Where does the `150.00` come from?

Comment: The amount is sum of amounts for that client for the month when he started his work, and it's not crucial for this query. @AaronDietz

Comment: `where day = 15` - and where is that? All you gave to as are year and month.

Comment: I edited my question and added ClientStartDate table, from which DAY and MONTH comes @IvanStarostin

Comment: So, based on given sample data, **where is 150 supposed to come from**?

Comment: I added full query and both tables that I use. @IvanStarostin

Comment: If you look at John, he started his work 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000, and Amount in first table in my question is sum(Amount) from FactTrans table for client with id=1 for whole month when he started his work, note that FactTrans table have a lot of records. @IvanStarostin

Comment: Hm.. I would suppose to define a cte in which you first get all names and all months required for your query. Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb6e7/7 - this can then be used in order to join your facts etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve